# MySQL Query Case

Tags: mysql, case

This is my code, i have 2 columns - **Modem = String**, **Total = Integer**

```
SELECT `Modem`, `Total`,
CASE `Modem` WHEN 'Yes' THEN
(`Total`+ 50)
ELSE
(`Total`+ 0)
END AS ModemAndTotal
FROM invoices
```

I need when Modem = "**Yes**" add 50 to total **(Total + 50)**

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve, do you really need 3rd column Modem and total? or you just want to replace column `Total`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT `Modem`, `Total`, CASE WHEN `Modem` = 'Yes' THEN (`Total`+ 50)
                         ELSE
                         `Total`
                        END AS ModemAndTotal
FROM invoices
```